# React router, codes after history.push run?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Say on your clickHandler

you do

```
// url change will cause this component to be dismounted and a new component will mount
history.push(url)

// do some more work 
dispatch(someMoreWork())
```

What happens to the code after the `push` call? is the code guaranteed to run?

Comment: I think it won't run, as the component will be dismounted

Comment: I think it will work, because javascript is sync language and can't ignore some piece of code. But the result can be unexpected, for example you can get an error like "you are trying to update state of unmounted component". You just don't need to use this pattern in your application if you don't want to have unexpected behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

history navigation is done only after the sync action within the event queue in javascript are executed.

In your case, javascript will executed all the things within the function where you call `history.push` and will then navigate to the new Route and it will be a predictable behaviour

You can simply validate the above by executing the dispatch action and then accessing the value in the rendered component.

[Check this  demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redux-o05y8?file=/reducers/index.js) that demonstrates the above behavior by dispatching an action after history.push and accessing the resultant redux state in the rendered route